# How can I look for similarities across an entire python dataframe?

Tags: python, similarity, euclidean-distance

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
            FG% FT% 3P%
Player A   .56 .80 .45
Player B   .22 .60 .20
Player C   .48 .71 .39

etc...
```

I'd like to iterate over each row (player) to find out which (for example) 5 players are closest to him for a given feature (or features).  For example, I'd like to get a list of the 5 players who are closest to player B in terms of FG% and FT%. Then I'd like to find the 5 players who are closest to player C, then player D, etc.

I know that Euclidean distance is somehow involved, but I'm not sure how to actually execute this and iterate over the entire dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean by `in terms of FG% and FT%`? 5 players for each one of the features, or 5 players for some combination of them?

Comment: @Aryerez it could be either or.  5 players who are closest to player X in terms of FT%.  And then iterate that code over each row to find the 5 players closest to each player (player A - 5 players who are closest, player B - 5 players who are closest, etc).